# Limit returned results with scrollable bar Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using the following pieces of code to generate a dynamic shoutbox on my site:

### HTML (index.html)

```
<body>

<div id="page">

    <div class="block_main rounded">
        <h2>My Shoutbox</h2>

        <form method="post" action="shout.php">
            Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            Message: <input type="text" id="message" name="message" class="message" /><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <div id="shout" style="padding:0 10px 0; overflow-x:hidden; height:225px;; overflow-y:auto;">

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //populating shoutbox the first time
    refresh_shoutbox();
    // recurring refresh every 15 seconds
    setInterval("refresh_shoutbox()", 15000);

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        // getting the values that user typed
        var name    = $("#name").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        // forming the queryString
        var data            = 'name='+ name +'&message='+ message;

        // ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $("#shout").slideToggle(500, function(){
                    $(this).html(html).slideToggle(500);
                    $("#message").val("");
                });
          }
        });    
        return false;
    });
});

function refresh_shoutbox() {
    var data = 'refresh=1';

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "shout.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html){ // this happen after we get result
                $("#shout").html(html);
            }
        });
}


</script>
</body>
```

### PHP Script (shout.php)

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB', 'User', 'PW');

if($_POST['name']) {
    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO shoutbox (date_time, name, message) VALUES (NOW(), :name, :message)";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':message', $message, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        populate_shoutbox();
    }
} 
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

if($_POST['refresh']) {
    populate_shoutbox();
}


function populate_shoutbox() {
    global $dbh;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM shoutbox ORDER BY date_time DESC limit 10";
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span class="date">'.date("m/d/Y g:i A", strtotime($row['date_time'])).'</span>';
        echo '<span class="name">'.$row['name'].'</span><br />';
        echo '<span class="message">'.$row['message'].'</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

The issue I am running into however is this, when the page initially loads, I set the `<div>` to a height of 300px with overflow-y:auto withint my CSS. When a user enter new information however (e.g. they enter a new message into the shoutbox), the area dynamic refreshes as it should but it no longer takes the div CSS scrollbar rules into consideration. How would I accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put `shout` into a container element and apply the slider stuff to it instead.

Comment: Did you maybe want to write `$("#message").html(html);` instead of `$("#shout").html(html);`?

Comment: @thejh - actually spoke too soon. Again, the scroll bar works perfectly at the start but if I actually insert data, the refresh simply extends all data beyond the scroll bars.

Comment: I think that it's because as soon as you click `submit`, that slideToogle stuff gets activated, but when `refresh_shoutbox()` fires, it maybe gets overwritten.

Comment: @thejh - I put my two full scripts (html and php call) in an updated question. I think your assumption is correct in your last post but it still does not seem to make sense to me given it *should* fall into the same rules given the returned data is still within the given <div style> set

Comment: Just looked it up - you have to put `shout` into another div (without changing anything in the code).

Comment: not sure I completely, follow. Do you mind writing out the line you mention?

Comment: instead of `<div id="shout"...</div>`, try `<div><div id="shout"...</div></div>` - here's a demo: http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: @thejh - why would putting the <div id="shout"> within another div do the trick? It is already siting within approximately 4 other divs to start. The code you mention does not work.

Comment: I am an idiot - I see what you are saying now. Div a has the 'style' format and div shout is within that.

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to mention that you have to set height for the outer one and the inner one. My fault.